# Pass variable to CtalendJob from route, create file and store it

Tags: java, talend, jobs, esb

Happy new year everyone :)

I'm new user of Talend studio, this is the second time I'm using ESB conductor and I think I'm doing something wrong here.

So, at the beginning I received a file from a SFTP then I depose it to another SFTP.
There is no problem here.
Second, after send this file, I need to create a second file, take the name of the first one send, rename it and depose it to the destination SFTP.

[My Route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/637qv.png)

So with the first component (cProcessor), I'm setting 2 variables :

- exchange.setProperty("target_directory", targetDirectory);
- exchange.setProperty("x_filename_trg", trgFileName);
  Here, I retrieve the right filename (xxx.trg) and the right targetDirectory.

Now I'm using a cTalendJob to call a job who can create an empty file :

[Inside cTalendJob](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXFzt.png)

To recover the variables of my routes, in my cTalendJob I checked "use context of the route"
In my tRouteInput I setted the schema like this [cRouteInput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUYNz.png)

Then I tried to create the new file on the folder :
[Create new file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfJnr.png)

At the moment my problem is : My variable are not transmitted to my cTalendJob. How can I transmit and use them properly ? [File Directory + FileName](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBBUk.png)
Can I send this file to the SFTP on the cTalendJob or need I to send it from my route ?

Thank you if you read me and if you can help me :)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say "hi" :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try by using a cSetHeader instead of cProcessor, to pass the variable as headers and not as properties ?

Comment: Thank you for reply, I'm late but I solve this problem.

Comment: Before my CtalendJob I used a cSetheader to pass variable to the job (check the propagate header in the cTalendJob) 

Then in my cTalendJob I use RouteInput => tJavaRow (to set globalMap variable) => tFileExist (to check if my new file exist) => tFileInputDelimited => tFileOutputDelimited to create the new file. 

At the end in the route after the cTalendJob just using a cFtp to send this new file. 

Thank you for help :)